# Angular ng-show doesn't work properly when value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to show div depends on permission of log in user.

```
<div class="container">
    <p> {{permission}}</p>
    <div ng-show="permission" class="admin_panel">
      ....
    </div>
</div>
```

and in controller, it is set:

```
$scope.init = function(){

    if($window.sessionStorage.isAdmin){
      $scope.permission = $window.sessionStorage.isAdmin;
    }
    $log.info("are you admin??? " + $scope.permission);
};
$scope.init();
```

In console, I could verify that permission was set to false and `{{permission}}` also showed 
its value is false. However, ng-show is still showing even though the value is false. I'm not sure what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried `ng-show="permission === true;"`? `ng-show`, to my understanding, is meant to evaluate whatever is inside the quotes. this would just explicitly state the evaluation. I've had experiences where just having a variable inside the quotes isn't an evaluation that `ng-show` recognizes for some odd reason.

Comment: ah I found why.. I thought sessionStorage.admin was set as boolean but it was string!!!! ugh

Comment: ngShow neither recognise having a simple function that return true / false.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem except that my variable was changed inside
a timeout function like this:

```
<div ng-show="check"> something .... </div>    

setTimeout(function(){
   check = false;
   },500);
```

the problem was solved when i added $scope.$apply() inside timeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   check = false;
   $scope.$apply()
   },500);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show or hide some content that depends of the user permissions, instead of using "ng-show", you should use "ng-if".

ng-show/ng-hide only adds or remove a CSS class that show or hide that element (display:none), but an user could change it easily in the browser.

Using ng-if: "If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM."

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Using `ng-if` is no more secure than `ng-show`. User may change `display`, but user may also manually insert the html element (bookmarklet, userscript, or typing in console). Permission verification MUST be done in server side in _both_ case.

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem and every thing work fine except ng-show. I missed something stupid. when you call a controller from different part of your document you can not share data between them. for example i have 2 div tag

### in document

```
<div id="1" ng-controller="contentCtrl">
   <div ng-click="toggleSidebarShow()">
   <!-- some code here -->
   </div>
</div>

<div id="2" ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    <div ng-show="showSidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

showSidebar between contentCtrl of div 1 and div2 wasn't share.

### in controller

```
// some code
    $scope.showSidebar = true;
    $scope.toggleSidebar = function (){
        $scope.showSidebar = ! $scope.showSidebar;
    };
```

but this code doesn't work because toggleSidebar called outside of the div2 tag and have it's own showSidebar. To conquer this problem you had to use service or modules. see [this](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services) link to more information.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to check is when your page loads, in the inspect element check if the element you are trying to use ng-show on is rendered inside the element which has the ng-controller directive.

If your element with ng-show is outside the ng-controller element then ng-show wont work

Answer (score 0):

i had this ng-show/hide problem sometimes... still in AngularJs v1.3.16

```
// this is not working sometimes
<td ng-hide="showrec == x.SeqNum>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="showrec = x.SeqNum; $apply()">xxx</a>
</td>

// but this version is
ng-click="showrecSeqNum(x)"

$scope.showrecSeqNum = function (x) {
  $scope.showrec = x.SeqNum;
//  $scope.$apply();
};
```